# Android Facebook SDK graphuser unicode

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, unicode, encoding, android-facebook

I am using Android Facebook SDK to integrate Facebook sign into my application. For that I need to get the user info from the facebook account. I do get this info, but if the name of the person is written in non-latin unicode letters, I get squares. All works fine with latin characters.

I get the information on the user like this:

```
 Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    String name = user.getFirstName());
                     // if the returned String is latin characters, it works fine


              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thesis done for a master course is available at this [link](http://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10211.10/1032/Bhasin_Dhruv.pdf?sequence=1). The project has done to support non-Latin language using Devanagiri font script as a model.